# navigationController push same view controller (self)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller (`HomeViewController`) and push another view controller (`UserProfileViewController`) in my `UserProfileViewController`, I want to push another instance of `UserProfileViewController`. How can I do that when I'm in `UserProfileViewController`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a reality check :-) Is this the right thing to do for your app? It sounds like a user could do this endlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new instance of that view controller and push it.
like:

```
UserProfileViewController *x = [[UserProfileViewController alloc] init];
[yourNavController pushViewController x];
[x release];
```

This new view controller will have a different address in memory, and will be entirely different from the current view controller.